# find element based on multiple condition in appium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, robotframework, ui-automation

I am creating an Ionic application which has different structure for different os so i want to target an element using multiple find-element method and want to execute the test. how to achieve these kind of condition based element target.

```
if (first input box){
//do this
}

if else (input place holder "userName"){
//do this
}

if else (id with "userName"){
//do this
}

else{
//failed
}
```

Comment: Which language & client do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just try/except?

```
Try:

   el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('ID')
   //do this

Except NoSuchElementException:
   pass

Try:

   el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('ID2')
   //do this

Except NoSuchElementException:
   pass

Try:

   el3 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('ID3')
   //do this

Except NoSuchElementException:
   self.faile('elements not found')
```

or something with "isDisplayed":

```
el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('ID')
if el1.is_displayed():
//do this
```